# Launched apps through i3blocks in a auto-hide enabled i3bar are not responding to mouse/keyboard

Tags: i3

I'm using (Linux) i3 window manager and in my settings I hold down the mod key to see my auto-hide enabled i3bar and then I click on an i3block to launch an app, then when I release the mod and i3bar is back to hidden state, the launched app isn't responding to mouse/keyboard anymore, the launched app responds to mouse/keyboard while I'm holding down the mod key and making the i3bar visible though.

I've tried launching the apps using nohup, disown, & and none of them made the process responsive to mouse/keyboard.

My settings could be found here:

i3blocks.conf: https://github.com/Faham/personal-linux-config/blob/master/.i3blocks.conf

i3.config: https://github.com/Faham/personal-linux-config/blob/master/.i3/config

Comment: [The i3 tag has been burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364438/shall-i3-you-from-an-off-topic-tag) on Stack Overflow. These questions are off-topic here. Please either use an appropriate StackExchange site or our official Q&A on reddit.

Comment: reported as bug here https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks/issues/293
thanks